# How to Select a row that Matches the text inside the input tag of row

Tags: jquery

I had a table to which rows are added dynamically which has text boxes inside td. what i want to do is before getting second row added it should check if the already exist in previous text boxes if yes add value to current value in another text box in row else add new row

What i have tried is

```
if (tdlength != 0) {
        $('tr.invoicerow').each(function () {
            var RowProductNames = $(this).find("input.invoiceproduct").val();
            if (RowProductNames == InvoiceProductName) {
                // Sum The Rate to Value alredy exists In text box
            } else {
                row = "<tr class='invoicerow'><td hidden><input class='dcid' value=" + deliverychallanid + "></td><td><input class='case invoicechkbox' type='checkbox'></td><td><input class='form-control invoiceproduct' id='invoiceproduct_" + rowno + "' value=" + InvoiceProductName + "></td><td><input class='form-control invoiceunit' id='invoiceunit_" + rowno + "' value=" + InvoiceUnit + "></td><td><input class='form-control invoicerate' id='invoicerate_" + rowno + "' value=" + InvoiceRatePerUnit + "></td><td><input class='form-control invoicenos' id='invoicenos_" + rowno + "'value=" + 0 + "></td><td><input class='form-control invoicequantity' id='invoicequantity_" + rowno + "' value=" + 0 + "></td><td><input class='form-control invoicecapacity' id='invoicecapacity_" + rowno + "'value=" + value.Capacity + "></td><td><input class='form-control invoiceamount' id='invoiceamount_" + rowno + "' value=" + Totalamount + "></td></tr>";
                $('#invoicebody').append(row);
            }
        });
        } else {
            row = "<tr class='invoicerow'><td hidden><input class='dcid' value=" + deliverychallanid + "></td><td><input class='case invoicechkbox' type='checkbox'></td><td><input class='form-control invoiceproduct' id='invoiceproduct_" + rowno + "' value=" + InvoiceProductName + "></td><td><input class='form-control invoiceunit' id='invoiceunit_" + rowno + "' value=" + InvoiceUnit + "></td><td><input class='form-control invoicerate' id='invoicerate_" + rowno + "' value=" + InvoiceRatePerUnit + "></td><td><input class='form-control invoicenos' id='invoicenos_" + rowno + "'value=" + 0 + "></td><td><input class='form-control invoicequantity' id='invoicequantity_" + rowno + "' value=" + 0 + "></td><td><input class='form-control invoicecapacity' id='invoicecapacity_" + rowno + "'value=" + value.Capacity + "></td><td><input class='form-control invoiceamount' id='invoiceamount_" + rowno + "' value=" + Totalamount + "></td></tr>";
            $('#invoicebody').append(row);

    }
```

When i tries this code what happens was 
First it checks with first row if text matches change in another text box is done 
Again it checks with second row text is not matched it adds New row and keeps on adding till loop is completes.. how to solve this

Thanks

Comment: What's your mean of ' if yes add value to current value'?

Comment: Let me explain u Bit clear when i add first row if it has two field in first field text is "foo" and second text value(rate) is"2" when i tries to add second row i will have some values if second text is also "foo"  add (newrate) to value in first row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See for this. I think this's what you want:

```
    var test = false;
    $('tr.invoicerow').each(function () {           
        var RowProductNames = $(this).find("input.invoiceproduct").val();
        if (RowProductNames == InvoiceProductName) {

            // Sum The Rate to Value alredy exists In text box
            test = true;
            return false;
        } 
    });
    if(!test){
        row = "<tr class='invoicerow'><td hidden><input class='dcid' value=" + deliverychallanid + "></td><td><input class='case invoicechkbox' type='checkbox'></td><td><input class='form-control invoiceproduct' id='invoiceproduct_" + rowno + "' value=" + InvoiceProductName + "></td><td><input class='form-control invoiceunit' id='invoiceunit_" + rowno + "' value=" + InvoiceUnit + "></td><td><input class='form-control invoicerate' id='invoicerate_" + rowno + "' value=" + InvoiceRatePerUnit + "></td><td><input class='form-control invoicenos' id='invoicenos_" + rowno + "'value=" + 0 + "></td><td><input class='form-control invoicequantity' id='invoicequantity_" + rowno + "' value=" + 0 + "></td><td><input class='form-control invoicecapacity' id='invoicecapacity_" + rowno + "'value=" + value.Capacity + "></td><td><input class='form-control invoiceamount' id='invoiceamount_" + rowno + "' value=" + Totalamount + "></td></tr>"
        $('#invoicebody').append(row);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be something like this,

```
$('tr.invoicerow').each(function () {

                    var RowProductNames = $(this).find("input.invoiceproduct").val();
                    if (RowProductNames == InvoiceProductName) {

                     var c=parseInt($(this).find("td input.invoicerate").val())+parseInt(USER_INPUTTED_VALUE);
                     $(this).find("td input.invoicerate").val(c);
                    } else {
                        row = "<tr class='invoicerow'><td hidden><input class='dcid' value=" + deliverychallanid + "></td><td><input class='case invoicechkbox' type='checkbox'></td><td><input class='form-control invoiceproduct' id='invoiceproduct_" + rowno + "' value=" + InvoiceProductName + "></td><td><input class='form-control invoiceunit' id='invoiceunit_" + rowno + "' value=" + InvoiceUnit + "></td><td><input class='form-control invoicerate' id='invoicerate_" + rowno + "' value=" + InvoiceRatePerUnit + "></td><td><input class='form-control invoicenos' id='invoicenos_" + rowno + "'value=" + 0 + "></td><td><input class='form-control invoicequantity' id='invoicequantity_" + rowno + "' value=" + 0 + "></td><td><input class='form-control invoicecapacity' id='invoicecapacity_" + rowno + "'value=" + value.Capacity + "></td><td><input class='form-control invoiceamount' id='invoiceamount_" + rowno + "' value=" + Totalamount + "></td></tr>"
                        $('#invoicebody').append(row);
                    }

                });
            }
```

Few things: i am assuming the class of textbox to set is `invoicerate`.Also assuming user is inputting the data in some other part of the form.
If not,please clarify.